# How to select players who are not two specific players in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Say I want to have a command that applies to everyone on a server except 2 people. Is there a target selector for that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do an all-but target selector, you need to add an exclamation point (!) before the name of the thing excluded from the command.

For example, the command

```
/testfor @a[name=!IfThenElse]
```

would return true if there is a player other than the player with the name IfThenElse online when the command is executed. In order to modify this command, simply replace the name IfThenElse with a different username.

With the all-but you can make an effective entity clearer:

```
/kill @e[type=!Player]
```

This would kill all entities (minecarts, mobs, dropped items) except for players.

However, since you can only select one all-but name, the scoreboard must be used.

Start by using the command

```
/scoreboard objectives add testnot dummy
```

and setting testnot to 1 on players you don't want to be effected by whatever command:

```
/scoreboard players set IfThenElse testnot 1
```

Replace IfThenElse with a username. Then you can run a command with the target selector
`@a[score_testnot=0]`, which would effect everyone but the players who had their testnot score set to 1.

I'm going to be surprised if I got the command syntax right. Edit as needed.

Comment: 2 people, not 1

Comment: @ModDL Would adding another `name=!` not work?

Comment: Nope, one per command

Comment: Well, oops. I'll change my answer on that case.

Answer (score 0):

Normal target selectors cannot select 2 specific people, the solution is to use a scoreboard to mark the players.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Selector dummy
```

Clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[name=<Name of Target>] Selector 1 //One of these commands per person
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Selector_min!=1] Selector 0
```

Selector:

```
@a[score_Selector=0] to select non selected
```

Comment: Do players automatically get added to the Selector scoreboard as having a score of 0?

Comment: Just reminded me that i needed to add them to the scoreboard

Comment: So why not just use `@a[score_Selector_min!=1]`in the first place? Also, what's `_min` do?

Comment: _min means the minimum amount of score they need, and well i guess you can do it with a _min=!1

Comment: So `@a[score_someVariable_min=1]` is basically how to do `@a[score_someVariable>=1]`, right?

Comment: Yep, the minimum of the score.

Answer (score 0):

So from what people have said and some of my own research here's the easiest way to do this:

1. Set up a scoreboard, called ExcludeSelection for example:

   `/scoreboard objectives add ExcludeSelection dummy`
2. Set the players you want to exclude to 1 in this scoreboard:

   `/scoreboard players set <username> ExcludeSelection 1` (do this for every player you want to exclude)
3. Add 0 to all player's scores (basically this adds players not on the scoreboard to the scoreboard without messing up existing values):

   `scoreboard players add @a 0` (in a loop, perhaps a [setblock clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit#Setblock_clock))
4. And then to select all players except the ones you want to exclude, just use:

   `@a[score_ExcludeSelection=0]`

I personally am using this to prevent anyone except the co-owners of the server (*moi* and my friend) from using creative mode. Just because I feel like it, here's what I think I'm going to do in addition to the first four steps.

In a setblock clock, I'll put `tell @a[score_ExcludeSelection=0,m=1] You are not allowed to use creative mode.` in one command block, and in another, `gamemode @a[score_ExcludeSelection=0,m=1] survival`.